# How can i configure a button in android app that will show all the available widgets for that app on click

Tags: android, android-widget

How can i configure a button in android app that will show  all the available widgets for that app on click. I can select any one widget and  that should be aded to my home screen.

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/pinning-shortcuts-widgets.html

```
PendingIntent successCallback = PendingIntent.createBroadcast(context, 0,
            pinnedWidgetCallbackIntent);
```

**`createBroadcast`** method is not getting resolved.

Comment: `PendingIntent` doesn't have `createBroadcast()` method. Do you mean `getBroadcast()`?

Comment: on developer.android.com its written as createBroadcast(). Thats confusing me.

Comment: I checked the link you mentioned. it's mentioned as `getBroadcast()` and not `createBroadcast()`

Comment: they removed the old page, see the url i have given, it will be redirected to some other page. there is no mention of widget pinning there.

Comment: Kindly check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#pinned

Comment: have you solved this problem? I have exactly same